# Proof that theta series are holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I am reading the proof that theta series are holomorphic in John Voight's *Quaternion Algebras* (Lemma 40.4.2), and I've run into an issue as my analysis is quite rusty (or perhaps was never that strong to begin with...).

Let $Q(x)$ be a positive definite quadratic form in $m = 2k$ variables and $\theta(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_Q(n) q^n$, where $r_Q(n)$ is the representation number of $n$ by $Q$. The author gives the following quick argument:

1. Since $Q$ is positive definite, there is $c \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $Q(x) \geq c(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_m^2)$.
2. Thus $r_Q(n) = O(n^k)$, and $\theta(z) \leq M \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^k q^n$.
3. Thus $\theta(z)$ is holomorphic.

I'm trying to fill in the details for $2$ implies $3$. I assume this is some simple application of the $M$-test, but I can't quite see it. Honestly, it's not even entirely clear to me that the $q$-series bounding $\theta(z)$ is holomorphic itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the author is using the convention that $q=e^{2\pi iz}$, so for every $\delta>0$, if $\Im(z)\ge\delta$, then

$$
|\theta(z)|\le1+\sum_{n\ge1}r_Q(n)e^{-2\pi n\delta}<1+M\sum_{n\ge1}n^ke^{-2\pi n\delta},
$$

so by the Weierstrass M-test, the $q$-series of $\theta(z)$ converges uniformly in every compact subset of the upper half plane $\mathbb H=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Im(z)>0\}$. This indicates that $\theta(z)$ is a holomorphic function in $\mathbb H$.

Comment: Right, I was just missing once the imaginary part is positive that series actually converges rather than being just a sum of kth powers. Thanks!